# Serving static files from Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to serve static files from `Node.js` the only problem I'm having, is if I keep going into sub paths, like so:

```
localhost:3000/foo/bar/baz/quux
```

Then I have to step up the same amount of times, like this:

```
../../../../public/javascripts/whatever.js
```

As you can see that gets really annoying, is there a way to make Express v3 just know so that I can just do `/public/javascripts/whatever.js` instead of having to step up? Thanks in advance

This is my current static middleware for Express`

```
app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With that `static()` configuration, Express is already at least capable of finding `/public/javascripts/whatever.js`.

Though, it does depend on whether your `public` folder is in the same directory as your script (due to the use of `__dirname` when specifying the path).

If it is, the URL prefix `/public` should map to the file-system prefix of `./public` (with `.` being  `__dirname`) so that:

```
A URL of `/public/javascripts/whatever.js`
Maps to `./public/javascripts/whatever.js`
```

Answer (score 3):

If you reference your static files from the root (i.e. `src='/some/path/to/file.js'`), the url should not matter.

### Example Website using Static Routing

#### Directory Structure

```
/public
    /css/style.css
    /js/site.js
/vendor/thoughtbrain/js/awesome-town.js
/views/view.html
/app.js
```

#### view.html

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- These files are served statically from the '/public' directory... -->
    <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <script src="/js/site.js"></script>
    <!-- ... while this is "mounted" in virtual '/public' -->
    <script src="/public/js/awesome-town.js"></script>
  </head>
<body><p>Express</p></body>
</html>
```

#### app.js

```js
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path'),
    app = express();

// Remember: The order of the middleware matters!

// Everything in public will be accessible from '/'
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Everything in 'vendor/thoughtbrain' will be "mounted" in '/public'
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'vendor/thoughtbrain')));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));

app.all('*', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('views/view.html')
});

http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
```

With this application running,

`http://localhost:3000`

and

`http://localhost:3000/foo/bar/baz/quux`

both serve **view.html** and all referenced assets resolve.

Express Framework has a section on the use of [static middleware here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use).